# Adding text to images using ImageMagick and Google Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, imagemagick, google-cloud-functions

Has anyone managed to get adding text to images working using ImageMagick within Google Cloud Functions? I tried using annotate, label, draw and had no luck with any. I am doing everything on the Google Cloud Functions web platform, so no need for mobile integration or anything.

Comment: Do any ImageMagick commands work?  What is the version of ImageMagick and what was your command syntax?  What delegates do you have installed? You can see from `convert -version` if on ImageMagick 6 or `magick -version` for ImageMagick 7. You may need to install freetype and fontconfig. Were you referencing the font by name or by path to the font file itself. The latter is the safest. The former needs each font to be entered in the type.xml file in order to be found by name.

Comment: Yeah, I have a handful of ImageMagik commands working such as covert, merge using multiple -page files, rotate, and resize. I was trying to reference the font via its name, but I didn't try referencing it via file path which is definitely a good idea. The label function would run and complete without any errors, but it would write nothing. I figured if it couldn't find the font it would have thrown me an error but that could very well be the issue. I'll give that a try and write back.

Comment: @fmw42 I have finally come back to this issue without any luck. Here are the couple lines of code I am currently using for text:
    const spawn = require('child-process-promise').spawn;
    const fontFile = bucket.file("folder/arial.ttf");
    const fontLocal = path.join(os.tmpdir(), "temp/arial.ttf");
    
    return fontFile.download({destination: fontLocal});
    .then(() => {
        return spawn ('convert',  [tempLocalFile, '-fill', 'blue', '-font', fontLocal, '-pointsize', '60', '-gravity', 'center', '-label', 'Insert Text Here', tempLocalFile]);
    });

Comment: `@BGitlin` I know nothing about Google Cloud functions, but try adding the full path to convert in your command.

Comment: Gotcha. Yeah I've tried doing something like this without any success:
return spawn ('convert',  [tempLocalFile, '-fill', 'blue', '-font', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto', '-pointsize', '160', '-gravity', 'center', '-label:', 'TEXT HERE', tempLocalFile]);

The format in my previous comment is the same format I use and have working for downloading and manipulating any other file within GCF so that seemed like the most promising way to get this working.

Comment: I meant add the full path to convert.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with https://www.npmjs.com/package/gm rather than spawn, seems like they have just stubbed all the text functions in whatever image they are using. Did you try pushing a font with your code? perhaps there are simply none installed? I'm trying that now, ill update here.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: Put a TTF file in the same directory as your function is executing in (mine was `/user_code`), and reference that font directly when you run graphics magick.

---

Alright, so I *seem* to have found some manner of solution. My circumstance is not exactly identical to yours, but I was seeing the exact same behavior you were. Rather than spawning a process, I am using the NPM GraphicsMagick wrapper library, GM (https://www.npmjs.com/package/gm). This should be very similar. I am also executing my functions via firebase functions, which is just running Google Cloud Functions, but I do not have access to the configuration so I can't verify that it is just using the defaults. I assume that this uses whatever the default Google Cloud Function image is. In any event, there is clearly some subset of ImageMagick installed on this image, and the normal text functions succeed, but do not modify the image output in any way.

The solution was ultimately to upload a font file with my code to use. System fonts like `arial` that you would expect to be available did not work. I used https://www.theleagueofmoveabletype.com/league-mono successfully, and used the following code to successfully draw text on Google Cloud Functions:

```
var gm = require('gm').subClass({ imageMagick: true });
require('gm-base64');

/* ...handler code... */ 

      gm(525, 110, '#ffffffdd')
        .fill('#000000dd')
        .drawCircle(100, 100, 120, 5)
        .font('font.ttf', 20)
        .fill('#00ff00dd')
        .drawText(100, 100, 'graphics')
        .toBase64('png', function(err, base64) {
          if (err != null) {
            throw err;
          }
          console.info(`got base64 encoding: ${base64}`);
          var img = new Buffer(base64, 'base64');

          res.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': 'image/png',
            'Content-Length': img.length,
          });
          res.end(img);
        });
```

This produced the following output:
[image: generated image]

I don't know the exact reason this works; I suspect there are no fonts installed in the image. I added alpha to everything because I wasn't certain that things weren't getting written over one another somehow.